# Filter NSArray of Object with NSArray of NSNumber with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

i'm trying to filer an array of this Object:

MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (assign) int id_object;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

So for example in my firstArray i have some MyObject:

```
MyObject *ob1 = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[ob1 setId_Object:1;
[ob1 setName:@"Carl"];

MyObject *ob2 = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[ob2 setId_Object:2;
[ob2 setName:@"Carl"];

MyObject *ob3 = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[ob3 setId_Object:3;
[ob3 setName:@"Carl"];

NSArray *firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ob1,ob2,ob3,nil];
```

then i want filter this array with NSPredicate with an array of NSNumber, like this:

```
NSArray *secondArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];
```

i have tried this:

```
 NSArray *filteredObject = [firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_object IN %@",secondArray]];
```

but the filteredObject is empty, how i can do?

Comment: show us firstArray array data.

Comment: you need to pass string not an array.

Comment: string of what? can you please answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be your test case that is wrong. I don't think your setId_object does what you think it does when calling it with an NSNumber;

```
[ob1 setId_object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
NSLog(@"%d", ob1.id_object);

> 391

[ob1 setId_object:1];
NSLog(@"%d", ob1.id_object);

> 1
```

Replacing the initializations makes your test case run ok.

EDIT: My test case, cut'n'pasted;

```
MyObject *ob1 = [[MyObject alloc] init]; ob1.id_object = 1; [ob1 setName:@"Carl"];
MyObject *ob2 = [[MyObject alloc] init]; ob2.id_object = 2; [ob2 setName:@"Carl"];
MyObject *ob3 = [[MyObject alloc] init]; ob3.id_object = 3; [ob3 setName:@"Carl"];

NSArray *firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ob1,ob2,ob3,nil];
NSArray *secondArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];

NSArray *filteredObject = [firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_object IN %@",secondArray]];

NSLog(@"%@", filteredObject);

>>> <MyObject: 0x100110350> {1,"Carl"}
>>> <MyObject: 0x1001104b0> {2,"Carl"}
```

Comment: that was only an example, i fill the firstArray in another way but i'm pretty sure that the array contains the correct value, my question is only about how i can filter that array...can you answer at the question please?

Comment: @Piero Making that small fix makes your code run with correct results for me. I can add my complete test case.

Comment: @Piero Updated with my test case.

Answer (score 0):

once check this one,

```
 NSArray *filteredObject = [questionSections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.Carl contains %@ OR self.Carl contains %@ ",@"1",@"2"]];
```

EX:-

```
 NSArray*  questionSections=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"List 3 rooms in your house?",@"name",@"301q.png",@"questionpicture",nil],[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Name a commonbird?",@"name",@"202q.png",@"questionpicture",nil], nil];


 NSArray *filteredObject = [questionSections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.questionpicture contains %@ OR self.questionpicture contains %@ ",@"2",@"3"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",filteredObject);
```

O/P:--

```
(
        {
        name = "List 3 rooms in your house?";
        questionpicture = "301q.png";
    },
        {
        name = "Name a common bird?";
        questionpicture = "202q.png";
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber* id_object;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

instead of

```
@property (assign) int id_object;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```